# Angular 2 URL bar use causes unwanted application reload

Tags: angular, browser

My program is a modification of the Angular 2 "Routing" advanced tutorial.  I can navigate to the correct places through my form controls.  But using the URL bar gives me problems.

Suppose that I've previously navigated to a feature, so that both login and  lazy loading has occurred.  If I type in its address in the URL I'm presented with my login page.  Tracing my code I'm starting at the very beginning again and previously lazy-loaded modules are now unknown to the system.

Or use the stock application from the Plunker page.  Once I've navigated to the Crisis Center #2 edit page I type into the url bar:

```
http://localhost:8000/crisis-center/1
```

I get this console error:

```
zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser:1274 GET http://localhost:8000/crisis-center/crisis-center/app/main.ts
```

My goal is that the access of crisis-center/1 should show me that record in the record editor page, which is the usual behavior through Angular 2 controls.  Instead the app begins to reload.  It fails to find localhost:8000/app/main.ts and instead loads localhost:8000/crisis-center/crisis-center/app/main.ts.

I suspect that there is something I'm supposed to be doing with browser local storage, but what?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses the pushState API, only when this API is used the URL can be changed without causing a page reload.

If you manually change the URL the browser reloads the URL. There is nothing you or Angular can do about it.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: That seems to constrain the user's behavior in an Angular application.  If I *really* wanted to I suppose I could store user state into local storage and do some preloading on startup.  I trade a behavior change for security issues.  Oh, well...

Comment: As mentioned this is not related to Angular. There is no way to prevent this, because it's how the browser handles URL changes. Yes, you can store user stat in local storage.